# How to disable floppy seek at linux startup?

Tags: centos, floppy

It is annoying enough that my BIOS has no switch that allows me to disable the floppy-seek at boot. But when I boot CentOS 5 the floppy seeks again - I suspect `hald` to do this.

How can I disable that seek (/dev/fd0)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the floppy drive is not in use anyway, the better solution may well be to simply disable the `floppy` module. You can do this as follows:

```
echo blacklist floppy > /etc/modprobe.d/00-disablefloppy.conf
```

Comment: It works. But perhaps there is a more generic answer. I remember disabling IDE on my servers at work so udev (or hald?) did not discover empty virtual DVDs (from RAC) - but that was SLES, and I have to look it up again...